# How to serialize Decimal Fields in mongoengine marshmallow?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, marshmallow

I have a decimal field in mongoengine, and I am trying to return the data I have stored in the model, but when I try to return the object I am receiving an error in the encoding

`TypeError: Object of type 'Decimal' is not JSON serializable`

```
class PaymentTransactionSchema(Document):
    meta = {
        'collection': 'payment_transaction'
    }
    payment_mode = StringField()
    payment_reference_code = StringField()

    currency = StringField()
    amount = DecimalField()
    status = StringField()

    approval_code = StringField()
    remarks = StringField()

    createdate = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)


class ProjectFundTransaction(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = ProjectFundTransactionSchema
```

then a return like this

```
self.__transaction = PaymentTransactionSchema(**args)
res = self.__transaction.save()
transaction = self.dump(res).data
```

I was hoping that the marshmallow would handle this automatically but it seems that I missed a config somewhere

Comment: You need set your `ProjectFundTransactionSchema`,  make it something like `class AlbumSchema(Schema):
    title = fields.Str()
    release_date = fields.Date()
    artist = fields.Nested(ArtistSchema())`

Comment: Do you serialize any Fields succeed?